# How to get unselected value in dropdown jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using following html for dropdown

```
<select class="form-control" id="iddeStatus" name="iddeStatus">
                                 <option value="">--Select ID De-dup Status--</option>
                                 <option value="PASSED">Passed</option>
                                 <option value="FAILED">Failed</option>
                              </select>
```

And below is my jquery code to get dropdown value

```
var iddeStatus = $("#iddeStatus").val();
 if((iddeStatus!=null)||(iddeStatus!="")){
...
}else{
...
}
```

Problem is, even if i dont select the value, control goes inside the if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason for behaviour:**

That is because you have or statement in if between if conditions. You need to use `&&` condition instead of `||`

```
if((iddeStatus!=null) && (iddeStatus!="")){
  ...
}
```

**Solution:**

You can narrow down the if condition to simply:

```
if(iddeStatus!="")){
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for truthyness of the value

```
var iddeStatus = $("#iddeStatus").val();
if (!iddeStatus) {
    //not selected
} else {//no need to have the else block if you don't have anything to do here
    //selected
}
```

or the opposite

```
var iddeStatus = $("#iddeStatus").val();
if (iddeStatus) {
    //selected
} else {
    //not selected
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code to get unselected value in dropdown jquery.

```
var iddeStatus = $("#iddeStatus").val();
if((iddeStatus!=null)||(iddeStatus!="")){
var unSelected = $("#iddeStatus").find('option').not(':selected');
     for (var i = 0; i < unSelected.length; i++) {
         alert(unSelected[i].text)
     }

}else{
alert('else part')
}
```